# Нужно ли делать сохранение на сервере, если в игре есть внутреигровые покупки?

Tags: google-play, unity3d-android

Есть игра на unity под google play. В игре есть внутреигровые покупки, к примеру возьмем отключение рекламы. Если человек купит этот товар и переустановит игру, то соответственно у него пропадет функйия блокировки рекламы. Вопрос: обязан ли я делать сохранение этих покупок, например через google play services, чтобы если игрок купил что-то, то это у него сохранилось навсегда?

Comment: По-моему, сохранить покупки игрока - это по крайней мере честно :)

Comment: Так то да, но я хочу понять обязательный ли это процесс с моей стороны

Comment: В принципе, если Вы разработчик игры, то нет ничего обязательного, только то, что Вы хотите. Но тут дело в доброчестности, я думаю, и отношении к игрокам. Поэтому, на Ваше усмотрение. Заставить-то Вас никто не может